# Subscribe to event in ViewModel from UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF application (a Reversi game) for school. I'm very new to MVVM, so excuse my *noobishness*.

I have a `StartScreen.xaml` bound to `StartViewModel` which represents the screen in the beginning of the game, and a `BoardScreen.xaml` bound to `BoardViewModel`, which is the screen with the Reversi board.

I use a `ContentControl` in `MainWindow.xaml` to display the screens. The ViewModels implement an abstract `Screen` class and I use a navigator to switch between them.

In my `BoardScreen.xaml.cs`, I'm trying to bind to an event from the `BoardViewModel`. The event is called `GameEnded` and is invoked when the game ends. I would like to subscribe to the event from the code behind (`BoardScreen.xaml.cs`) in order to play a sound when the game is ended. Something like this:

```
GameEnded += BoardScreen_GameEnded
...
private void BoardScreen_GameEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaySound(WinSound);
}
```

The problem is that I really don't know how to get to that event. I can't seem to access it using the `DataContext` or `Content` properties.

Does anyone have any idea how to go about this? If I need to clarify further, please ask. Thanks! :)

**`MainWindow.xaml`**

```
<Window x:Class="View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Reversi"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentScreen}" Margin="30" />
</Window>
```

**`App.xaml`**

```
<Application x:Class="View.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:View"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins\blue.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StartViewModel}">
                <view:StartScreen />
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BoardViewModel}">
                <view:BoardScreen />
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**`Navigation.cs`**

```
public abstract class Screen
{
    protected readonly Navigator navigator;

    protected Screen(Navigator navigator)
    {
        this.navigator = navigator;
    }

    protected void SwitchTo(Screen screen)
    {
        this.navigator.CurrentScreen = screen;
    }
}

public class Navigator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Screen currentScreen;

    public Navigator()
    {
        this.currentScreen = new StartViewModel(this);
    }

    public Screen CurrentScreen
    {
        get
        {
            return currentScreen;
        }
        set
        {
            this.currentScreen = value;

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentScreen)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action action;

    public SimpleCommand(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

**`BoardScreen.xaml`**

```
public partial class BoardScreen : UserControl
{
    public System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer ClickSound { get; private set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer WinSound { get; private set; }

    public BoardScreen()
    {
        // Initialize sounds
        ClickSound = new MediaPlayer();
        WinSound = new MediaPlayer();

        ClickSound.Open(new Uri(@"..\..\Sounds\click.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
        WinSound.Open(new Uri(@"..\..\Sounds\win.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void BoardScreen_GameEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlaySound(WinSound);
    }

    private void PlaySound(MediaPlayer sound)
    {
        sound.Stop();
        sound.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        sound.Play();
    }

    internal void PlayClickSound(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlaySound(ClickSound);
    }

    internal void PlayWinSound(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlaySound(WinSound);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @Spongebrot mentioned in the comments, I was able to subscribe to the event by doing it inside the DataContextChanged event. Type checking is necessary, as I would get a NullPointerException otherwise.

```
DataContextChanged += (o, e) => {
    if(DataContext is BoardViewModel)
    {
        var viewModel = DataContext;
        (DataContext as BoardViewModel).GameEnded += BoardScreen_GameEnded;
    }    
};
```

Comment: It should work if you add the event inside the DataContextChanged event of the UserControl this.DataContextChanged += (o,e) => { var viewModel = this.DataContext; };

Comment: I use Prisms Event Aggregator in my MVVM apps which in my opinion is my bar the easiest and most decoupled way of using events. It works by injecting the EventAggregator into any objects that may need it, and then publishing or subscribing to a specific event - in your case the GameEnded event. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ffb84/prism-event-aggregator-in-wpf-with-mvvm/

Comment: @Spongebrot this works at first, however, when the game ends, I can press a button that takes me back to the StartScreen and when I click it I get a NullReferenceException on the line where I subscribe to the event... No idea why :/

Comment: @Spongebrot I fixed by checking if the DataContext was the correct ViewModel type! Thank you!